# Django - some permissions are missing in admin tool

Tags: python, django, eclipse, django-admin, django-permissions

I'm not quite sure what to make of this.  I'm using Django in eclipse.  I made a new django project, and copied the code from a previous django project into this one.  I ran syncdb to set up the database.  I went to the admin page to recreate my groups, but I noticed that some of the permissions were missing from the list of Available permissions.  In the previous project, there was a permission to let me "access" a profile.  In this project, that permission isn't on the list, but it's also the permission that I need.  Where did it go?

Comment: Were all the other tables created when you ran syncdb?

Comment: I believe so, yes.  What's weird is, I used to have 4 permissions available for each profile object, an add, a delete, a change, and an access permission.  The other three are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where did it go?

When you incrementally change your database by dropping tables and running syncdb, the PK of the application table are reflected  in the `auth_permission` table can change.

Don't do "incremental" surgery if you can avoid it.

1. Extract your data.
2. Drop your database.
3. Rerun syncdb to rebuild it.
4. Reload your data.

You'll be much happier.

Comment: My database is the sqlite db that eclipse makes and sticks in the folder.  I'm not really sure how to access it other than through the admin interface.  Maybe through the shell?  Usually I just delete the database file but that would lose all the data

Comment: @JPC: You can easily write small Python applications to get data in and out of this database using Django models and CSV files.  You can also use the `sqlite3` module in Python for low-level access to the database.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get that sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

This question came up on a search for why django was giving me a "Permission not Found" error during a data migration that creates my default permission groups when I was creating a fresh db instance.

For me, the answer was related to how permissions are created during the "post migration signal" step. So when building migrations incrementally, that signal is emitted which creates the permissions. But when rebuilding the database this signal is not emitted until the final migration completes successfully. So if one of your data migrations references permissions then you will get the error I encountered. Specifically, our data model changed significantly during development so we cleared the migrations, copied in the data migrations, and issued `migrate`

A great discussion is here: https://www.webinative.com/blog/django-permission-not-found-error/

The solution is to force create the permissions prior to whatever data migration needed them.

```py
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions

def force_create_permissions(apps, schema_editor):
    """ creates permissions without waiting for post_migrate signal """
    for app_config in apps.get_app_configs():
        app_config.models_module = True
        create_permissions(app_config, apps=apps, verbosity=0)
        app_config.models_module = None

[ the rest of your data migration logic...]

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        (...),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(force_create_permissions),
        migrations.RunPython(...)
    ]
```

Big thanks to the linked blog post and all credit goes to Magesh Ravi (the author)!

To this question, I'm wondering if one of the data migration steps in the original project included this step, but a later one did not, so there were SOME permissions, but not all.